# XQuery check for empty element and return a default value if the element is empty

Tags: timestamp, xquery

I have an Xquery question. I have a timestamp element in my output xml, which needs to take the value of an element from the input xml only if it exists, otherwise it should return a default value. How do I accomplish this:

For example, my input xml looks like this:

```
<test>
    <timestamp1>2014-12-31T12:00:00.285Z</timestamp1>
    <timestamp2></timestamp2>
</test>
```

I need to write an xquery to return the following xml:

```
<response>
    <time1>2014-12-31T12:00:00.285Z</time1>
    <time2>2038-01-02T00:00:00.285Z</time2>
    <time3>2038-01-02T00:00:00.285Z</time3>
</response>
```

Note that my output xml should contain all the three time elements and none can be empty. Eventhough my input xml does not contain  element (which would have been where the  element in my output xml would have gotten its value from), still the output needs to have the corresponding  element.

Any help will be much appreciated! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: There are an infinite number of timestamp elements not contained in your input.  Do your requirements really say that for each timestamp element not contained in the input, you must produce a time element in the output?

Comment: just those 3 timestamps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will default to the time in your output if the the `timestampX` element is empty:

```
declare function local:first-or-default(
  $time as xs:dateTime
) as xs:dateTime
{
  (., xs:dateTime('2038-01-02T00:00:00.285Z'))[1] 
};

let $test := 
  <test>
      <timestamp1>2014-12-31T12:00:00.285Z</timestamp1>
      <timestamp2></timestamp2>
  </test>

return 
  element response {
    $test/timestamp1/element time1 { local:first-or-default(.) }
    $test/timestamp2/element time2 { local:first-or-default(.) }
    $test/timestamp3/element time3 { local:first-or-default(.) }
  }
```